# ACF: Display Google Map in frontend issues

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I have a CTP with an ACF Google Map field. The values in this field come from somewhere external via APIs.

I set the API right because in backend I see correctly longitude, latitude and address and the Google Map works.

However when I try to render the map in frontend following [this](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/) guide, what I get is a map with no marker and with wrong longitude and latitude (somewhere in the ocean).

In my functions.php file I have this

```
//GOOGLE MAPS API KEY
function my_acf_init() {
     
    acf_update_setting('google_api_key', 'MY_API_KEY');
}
 
add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
```

In my CPT Template I have this

```
<style type="text/css">
.acf-map {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
border: #ccc solid 1px;
margin: 20px 0;
}

// Fixes potential theme css conflict.
.acf-map img {
   max-width: inherit !important;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {

/**
 * initMap
 *
 * Renders a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
 *
 * @date    22/10/19
 * @since   5.8.6
 *
 * @param   jQuery $el The jQuery element.
 * @return  object The map instance.
 */
function initMap( $el ) {

// Find marker elements within map.
var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

// Create gerenic map.
var mapArgs = {
    zoom        : $el.data('zoom') || 16,
    mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], mapArgs );

// Add markers.
map.markers = [];
$markers.each(function(){
    initMarker( $(this), map );
});

// Center map based on markers.
centerMap( map );

// Return map instance.
return map;
}

/**
 * initMarker
 *
 * Creates a marker for the given jQuery element and map.
 *
 * @date    22/10/19
 * @since   5.8.6
 *
 * @param   jQuery $el The jQuery element.
 * @param   object The map instance.
 * @return  object The marker instance.
 */
function initMarker( $marker, map ) {

// Get position from marker.
var lat = $marker.data('lat');
var lng = $marker.data('lng');
var latLng = {
    lat: parseFloat( lat ),
    lng: parseFloat( lng )
};

// Create marker instance.
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : latLng,
    map: map
});

// Append to reference for later use.
map.markers.push( marker );

// If marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow.
if( $marker.html() ){

    // Create info window.
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: $marker.html()
    });

    // Show info window when marker is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open( map, marker );
    });
}
}

/**
 * centerMap
 *
 * Centers the map showing all markers in view.
 *
 * @date    22/10/19
 * @since   5.8.6
 *
 * @param   object The map instance.
 * @return  void
 */
function centerMap( map ) {

// Create map boundaries from all map markers.
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
map.markers.forEach(function( marker ){
    bounds.extend({
        lat: marker.position.lat(),
        lng: marker.position.lng()
    });
});

// Case: Single marker.
if( map.markers.length == 1 ){
    map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );

// Case: Multiple markers.
} else{
    map.fitBounds( bounds );
}
}

// Render maps on page load.
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.acf-map').each(function(){
    var map = initMap( $(this) );
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

And this is how I am trying to render the map in front end

```
<?php 
    $location = get_field('map');
    if( $location ): ?>
        <div class="acf-map" data-zoom="16">
            <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo esc_attr($location['lat']); ?>" data-lng="<?php echo esc_attr($location['lng']); ?>"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This is my ACF Field. The filed name is “map”

```
<?php $map = get_field( 'map' ); ?>
<?php if ( $map ) : ?>
<?php echo $map['address']; ?>
<?php echo $map['lat']; ?>
<?php echo $map['lng']; ?>
<?php echo $map['zoom']; ?>
<?php $optional_data_keys = array('street_number', 'street_name', 'city', 'state', 'post_code', 'country'); ?>
<?php foreach ( $optional_data_keys as $key ) : ?>
    <?php if ( isset( $map[ $key ] ) ) : ?>
        <?php echo $map[ $key ]; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any hint? :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after the last update. The solution for me was to go back to the old version. Hope it solves in the next update.